# How to delete route to a particular node in the agent?

Tags: unetstack

I want to delete routing entries from routing table to a node 1 from the agent but i am not able to figure out how to write code for deleting routing entries to a particular node through my own agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`EditRouteReq`](https://unetstack.net/javadoc/3.3/org/arl/unet/net/EditRouteReq.html) in the [`ROUTING`](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_routing_and_route_maintenance.html) service of UnetStack. The `EditRoutReq` has constructors that allow deletion of route that match specific criteria (e.g. `EditRouteReq.deleteRoute()` or `EditRouteReq.deleteRoute(String uuid)`). Sending this request to the router (agent offering the `ROUTING` service should do what you want.

Example code snippet to delete route with UUID `id`:

```
r = EditRouteReq.deleteRoute(id)
r.recipient = agentForService(Services.ROUTING)
request(r, 1000)
```

or to delete all routes to destination address `addr`:

```
r = EditRouteReq.deleteRoute()
r.to = addr
r.recipient = agentForService(Services.ROUTING)
request(r, 1000)
```